# cmd.exe being executed during boot cycle

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, cmd.exe

I have a problem during the boot cycle. This problem started after the April 2015 Updates. I see a cmd box appearing, a cmd line appearing and before I can see what the command is the box disappears. I am concerned that I might have a virus but neither Bitdefender nor MalwareByte find anything wrong. I need to keep the box open long enough to see the command executing. What can I do?

Comment: did you tried to check if something is executing in start?  Click the Start button > click All Programs, right-click the Startup folder, and then click Open. and Start > Run > msconfig (intro) and check if something wrong is running in start there

Comment: ue process monitor and do a boot log. Look at the process tree which processes call CMD.exe

Answer (score 1):

There are many places in Windows where startup applications can be set. To see all of them, you could try and run the [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) application to see if you can identify which application it is you're looking for.